# Java 8 Streams - Reading, logic and printing to file in a single stream

Tags: file-io, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to read a file with some strings and numbers then filter numbers from strings, append all numbers in every line and print it into a new file.
I know it may be a bit challenging but is it even possible to do such a thing in only one stream?

e.g input

```
some numbers   1   2   3
number   4   5   6
and few more number  7   8   9
```

e.q output

```
1+2+3 = 6
4+5+6 = 15
7+8+9 = 24
```

My main class for testing

```
public class MainFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filePath = "src/test/recources/1000.txt";
        new FileProcesorStream().fileReader(filePath);

    }
}
```

and so far I did smth like this.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileProcesorStream {
    public void fileReader(String fileName) {

        try (Stream<String> streamReader = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
             PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("resultStream.txt")) {

            streamReader
                    .filter(line -> line.matches("[\\d\\s]+"))
                    .forEachOrdered(printWriter::println);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this at least a good start to solve this problem or if not with what should I start or what should I change?
Of course, if it's it possible only with a single stream.

Comment: intersting, you are saying `append` (which assumes `123`, `456`, etc); give an example where you do an addition and accept an answer that does just the sum. So which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String::replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) along with the regex `[^\\d\\s]+` which after that specific `map` operation should provide us a string containing only the whitespaces and the numbers, which we then perform a [String::trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) operation to remove the leading and trailing whitespace.

Following that we compute the sum of the numbers for each of the lines.

```
streamReader
.map(line -> line.replaceAll("[^\\d\\s]+", ""))
.map(String::trim)
.mapToInt(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
                        .map(String::trim)
                        .filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                        .sum()
)
.forEachOrdered(printWriter::println);
```

Comment: this can (and should be simplified), at least the fact that you are first matching `\\s` to only trim it after - don't match it in the first place... there are probably ways to make my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48612557/1059372 java-8 compatible via `Stream#iterate` may be or something the like, but not in the mood to think too much about it :|

Answer (score 0):

In java-9 if you even will upgrade, there a simpler way to get those sums (via `Scanner#findAll`) :

```
   streamReader.map(Scanner::new)
               .mapToInt(s -> s.findAll("\\d+")
                    .map(MatchResult::group)
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .sum())
               .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```